# Unittest Discovery Finds Tests Outside Discovery Pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

[Unittest discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest-test-discovery) default is to find tests in files starting with `test`.  But for me it is finding tests that do not meet that criteria.  Here is my structure:

```
project
|   __init__.py
|   stuff.py
└───test_folder
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   test_stuff.py
│   └───framework_folder
│       │   __init__.py
│       │   framework.py
```

I've created a test framework class to handle testing a lot of similar objects. It subclasses `unittest.TestCase` and has a few methods that begin with `test_`.  Then `test_stuff.py` subclasses the framework and overrides a few supporting methods; the inherited `test_` methods are the actual tests.

The thing is, `framework.py` itself is not meant to be tested, and under the default discovery conventions, it doesn't look to me like it should be, as the file name doesn't begin with `test_`. **But it is.**

I see a lot of questions about unittest not discovering tests, but not any about discovering the wrong ones.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I ultimately worked around the issue by making mixins and subclassing those.  However, I still don't know why those tests were discovered.

Comment: are you adding stuff from `framework.py` into the `__init__.py` of `test_folder`?

Comment: I now came across a very similar problem. I have a subfolder with test data in it. One of the files is called `test_data.csv` and it is discovered as test despite I have configured the pattern to be `test_*.py`. I would love to see an answer to this!